# Bootstrap column adjustment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 I am trying to bring two columns next to each other.Below is my .
[bootplyurl](http://www.bootply.com/ls2rECrRZ5)

I am trying to bring filter drop down next to export with less space between them

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<div class="col-md-10"><br>
    <class="col-md-8">
```

with

```
<div class="col-md-10"><br>
    <div class="col-md-8">
```

Comment: Thx ramis.I blt adjusted still filter comes in next column I am trying to make both export and filter next to each other. see my updated bootply.http://www.bootply.com/x5EJoxhRMP

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a right attribute onto the container div of either button. This example uses the container div of the filter button.

```
body > div.form-inline > div > div.col-md-4 > div {
  right: 50px; /*however far you would like */
}
```